# Downloading file from Database hangs IE if asp:fileupload field is used

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, download

IE Version 11

If the first thing i do is downloading a file it works. But if i use the asp:fileupload field the IE and chose file i want to download after i submit the form and after that i want to use the download link to download a file from my sql database the IE just loads forever and i cant press anything. (It works in the latest Firefox and Chrome)

Here is the HTML markup, the Repeater for the Download links and the asp:fileupload:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterDatein" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RepeaterDatein_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" class="downloadfile" ID="LinkButton1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("dataId") %>' CommandName="download"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "dataName") %></asp:LinkButton><br />
            </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>

    <!-- Upload Multiple Files -->
    <div id="fileUploadarea"><asp:FileUpload ID="fuPuzzleImage" runat="server" CssClass="fileUpload" /></div>
```

This is the c# code for the download of a file from the Databas when the ItemCommand is fired:

```
 try {
            if (e.CommandName == "download") {
               Arbeitsmeldung hinzugefügt wird
                string id = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                string fileName;
                byte[] bytes;

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

                cmd.CommandText = "Select dataName,dataFile FROM datein WHERE dataId = @dataId";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataId", id);
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                conn.Open();


                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                    sdr.Read();
                    fileName = sdr["dataName"].ToString();
                    bytes = (byte[])sdr["dataFile"];
                }

                conn.Close();

                Response.Clear();   
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            this.Session["exceptionMessage"] = ex.Message;
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("Error.aspx");
        }
```

What happens when i click the asp:FileUpload, browse for data and chose a file. It is not uploaded before i press the submit button, what kind of data does the browser store and how can this be in conflict with the filedownload ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this code in your download Button.....

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + dt.Rows[0]["v_file"]);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("upload/") + dt.Rows[0]["v_file"]);
Response.End();
```

Comment: the File is in a SQL Database and not inside a folder on the server.

If i creat a folder upload and place the file inside and use this code i get the same problem, i can download it aslong as i dont use the asp:UploadFile field to chose a file i want to upload when i submit the form